# Ninject in combination with Owin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I'm trying to figure our how can I provide my Entity framework context to owin so that my authentication works properly. I'm initializing Owin like this:

```
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {        
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppContext>(AppContext.Create); // creates EF context
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
            ....
        }
```

And ApplicationUserManager looks like:

```
        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {               
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<AppContext>()));
            ....
         }
```

Authentication and everything else works properly this way. As you can see I'm getting AppContext from owin context which I previously initialized.

I would like to Inject this using Ninject instead so that it would look like:

```
            public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
            {
                // get app context from Ninject kernel
                var appContext = KernelProvider.Kernel.Get<AppContext>();
                var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(appContext));
                ----
             }
```

In AppContext I'm initializing the CurrentUser like:

```
        public AppContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", false) // set IsIdentityV1Schema to false to prevent executing additional SQL queries
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
                {
                    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated != false)
                    {
                        currentIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This does not work if I inject AppContext via Ninject. Is there a way to make this work or is there maybe some other better way?

Thanks for any suggestions!